# NodeJS: Parsing HTML HTML and inline SVG graphics with Cheerio

Tags: node.js, express, svg, cheerio

I am developing a Node ExpressJS application, which shall crawl a HTML document, containing a inline SVG structure (SVG as an HTML tag, defining a SVG graphic).

This SVG structure contains a lot "subtags" of type text, the attributes an inner text I want to extract of, using Cheerio.
Unfortunately my Node application crashes, once it gets to reading attribute values of one of the SVG text attributes.
Find the error message thrown below; unfortunately its not very meaningful. It crashes both on Windows and Linux platforms.

Using the same selectors with pure jQuery and JS in a real browser environment, to extract the data is working fine, it just seems to be Cheerio.
Is there maybe another way of parsing inline SVG structures?

Error message:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "<path to node executable>" "<path to node modues>\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! myapp@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
[...]
```

Comment: I guess we need to see your code and an example document to really help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the reason for failing lies within my implementation, not with in Cheerio.
My implementation assumed a real Browser DOM; of course that's not the case on NodeJS.

In my case, I had some array sorting closure

```
jQuery(selector).toArray().sort(function(a, b){
        var aVal = parseInt(a.getAttribute(attrName)),
            bVal = parseInt(b.getAttribute(attrName));
        return aVal - bVal;
})
```

which worked fine within a real browser and real jQuery, but failed on NodeJS using Cheerio.

I rewrote my code to "re-jQueryfy" the selected element within the sorting closure, using `jQuery(a).attr(attrName)`, instead of `a.getAttribute(attrName)`:

```
jQuery(selector).toArray().sort(function(a, b){
    var aVal = parseInt(jQuery(a).attr(attrName)),
        bVal = parseInt(jQuery(b).attr(attrName));
    return aVal - bVal;
});
```

I guess the reason lies within NodeJS itself, not Cheerio, since there is no DOM available, with selectable elements supporting `getAttribute` function.